# Salvattore grid stopped working after adding angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I added angularjs to my project, [Salvattore](http://salvattore.com/) grid stopped working, it's not rendering.

I want to use ng-repeat functionality to loop through all the items and display them in Salvattore grid.

What can cause this? Thanks

Comment: Here is codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrNaex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like what's happening is, Salvattore assumes that the elements it needs to apply masonry layouts are present in the dom by the time you add `data-columns` attribute and of course this wont work because `ng-repeat` takes a digest cycle to add the elements to dom.

One way to get around this is to create a custom directive that would initialise `data-columns` after elements are present in dom.

One quick way (probably not the most robust) would be to add that `data-columns` attribute after a digest cycle.

Here's an implementation:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('grid', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
      'test1','test2','test3','test4',
      'test5','test6','test7'
  ];
});

app.directive('salvattore', function($timeout, $window) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          $timeout(function(){ //Hack to execute on next timeout
            element.attr('data-columns', true);
            $window.salvattore.register_grid(element[0]);            
          },0);
        }
      };
});
```

```css
.grid[data-columns]::before {
  content: '3 .col-4';
}

.grid {
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/salvattore/1.0.9/salvattore.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
<div class="container" ng-controller="grid">

<h4>With angularjs</h4>
<div class="row grid" salvattore>
  <div class="entry" ng-repeat="e in data">{{e}}</div>
</div>
  
  
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the directive:

```
app.directive('salvattore', function($timeout, $window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function(){ //Hack to execute on next timeout
        element.attr('data-columns', true);
        $window.salvattore.register_grid(element[0]);            
      },0);
    }
  };
```

});

Note: The directive is inspired by https://github.com/nathankot/angular-salvattore

Oh and here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBrVpm

Comment: NOO Filtering the entries (e in data | filter:search) is not working http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpebNV

Comment: It wasn't. I've actually rewritten your directive here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595787/filter-not-working-ng-repeat/42596262#42596262 thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've added the directive (and attr inside html) that Chanthu wrote and `ng-if="array.length>0"` works for me.