# Filter not working ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using **[Salvattore](http://salvattore.com/)** (masonry like grid) in my angular app but the filter option in `ng-repeat` does not work.
I think it's because **Salvattore** wraps each repeated item in a separate `div` to make a grid (in my example it's `div.col-4`)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<div class="row grid" salvattore>
  <div class="entry" ng-repeat="e in data | filter:search">
    {{e}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The output of the above is similar to the following:

```
<div class="row grid" salvattore="" data-columns="3">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="entry">e</div>
    <div class="entry">e</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="entry">e</div>
    <div class="entry">e</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    ..
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this is what causes the problem with filtering... but I'm not really sure to be honest :)

**The question is:**  *What should I do to make it work? Do I have to crate a custom filter?*

I've created a codepen for this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpebNV

Thanks.

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: @GeomanYabes The question is what to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

So the salvattore incompatible with angular. You can write a directive to implement its function. Or use jquery to implement a "filter" function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write my own directive and it seems to be working quite good.
I've added the following to the salvattore directive.

```
app.directive('salvattore', function($timeout, $window,$filter) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      // First load (does not work without it
      $timeout(function(){
        element.attr('data-columns', true);
        $window.salvattore.register_grid(element[0]);            
      },0);



    scope.$watch('search', function(newValue, oldValue) {


    // I needed this hack because the grid didn't render properly when $scope.search was empty
    if(newValue=='') {
      var filteredData = scope.data;
      var items = '';
      jQuery.each(filteredData, function(index, entry){
        var ITEM_TEMPLATE = '<div class="entry">{{e}}</div>';
          var content = ITEM_TEMPLATE.replace(/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/g, function (match, g1) {
            switch (g1) {
              case 'e': return entry; break;
            }
          });
          items = items.concat(content);
      });
      jQuery('.grid').html(items);
      $window.salvattore.register_grid(element[0]);
    }


    if (newValue) {
      var filteredData = $filter('filter')(scope.data, scope.search);
      var items = '';
      jQuery.each(filteredData, function(index, entry){
        var ITEM_TEMPLATE = '<div class="entry">{{e}}</div>';
          var content = ITEM_TEMPLATE.replace(/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/g, function (match, g1) {
            switch (g1) {
              case 'e': return entry; break;
            }
          });
          items = items.concat(content);
      });
      jQuery('.grid').html(items);
      $window.salvattore.register_grid(element[0]);
    }

}, true);


    }
  };
});
```

I know it looks primitive but it is what it is, but I also know it can be simpler. Maybe someone can check this and improve a little bit, please?

Here's codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpebNV